# why sorry pop up cause of text size?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button, android-textattributes

I have a layout with a textview and a button as below.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/info_layout">        

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"  />

<Button android:id="@+id/butn1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above layout works fine for many languages but for arab its giving sorry pop up, but if i change textSize to 18sp it works fine. Even i tried removing margin from button before changing text size but still the problem raises.I'll set text for text View in java file.So im not understanding what's exact cause for this problem.

```
  01-08 03:09:59.959: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=75; regionStart=52; regionLength=-18
```

Comment: Its not a force close but something like Unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: I think you have added `Localized` values in your `res` folder? and you forget to add `String with name button1`.

Comment: Its StringIndexOutOfBoundsException i have updated

Comment: can you add full logcat message along with java code because the XML you have posted is looking fine.. i think it has something to do with your java code.